# Downgrade Chrome version to 74 in CircleCI

Tags: selenium, meteor, circleci

I'm running a Meteor App and using CircleCI. For integration tests I'm using selenium-webdriver 3.6.0 which only supports Chrome version 74. The problem is that I cannot install Chrome 74, it automatically installs version 76 and I get this error:

`This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74`

If I try to update `selenium-webdriver` I get this error:

`The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10.15.0". Got "8.15.1"`

I cannot update Node since I'm using Meteor, which uses Node 8.15.1.

Full error:

```
I20190809-11:38:44.138(-3)? --------------------------------
I20190809-11:38:44.138(-3)? --- RUNNING APP CLIENT TESTS ---
I20190809-11:38:44.139(-3)? --------------------------------
W20190809-11:38:56.725(-3)? (STDERR) /home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2626
W20190809-11:38:56.726(-3)? (STDERR)         throw error;
W20190809-11:38:56.726(-3)? (STDERR)         ^
W20190809-11:38:56.726(-3)? (STDERR) 
W20190809-11:38:56.726(-3)? (STDERR) SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
W20190809-11:38:56.727(-3)? (STDERR)   (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 5.0.0-23-generic x86_64)
W20190809-11:38:56.727(-3)? (STDERR)     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
W20190809-11:38:56.727(-3)? (STDERR)     at parseHttpResponse (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
W20190809-11:38:56.727(-3)? (STDERR)     at doSend.then.response (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
W20190809-11:38:56.728(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/vallo/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.2.1rxqxdq.d4m4g++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
W20190809-11:38:56.728(-3)? (STDERR) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
W20190809-11:38:56.730(-3)? (STDERR)     at Function.createSession (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
W20190809-11:38:56.733(-3)? (STDERR)     at Function.createSession (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
W20190809-11:38:56.734(-3)? (STDERR)     at createDriver (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
W20190809-11:38:56.734(-3)? (STDERR)     at Builder.build (/home/vallo/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:642:16)
W20190809-11:38:56.734(-3)? (STDERR)     at startChrome (packages/meteortesting:browser-tests/browser/chromedriver.js:46:136)
W20190809-11:38:56.735(-3)? (STDERR)     at startBrowser (packages/meteortesting:browser-tests/server.js:23:7)
W20190809-11:38:56.735(-3)? (STDERR)     at clientTests (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:140:3)
W20190809-11:38:56.735(-3)? (STDERR)     at serverTests (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:185:7)
W20190809-11:38:56.735(-3)? (STDERR)     at mochaInstance.run.failureCount (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:120:13)
W20190809-11:38:56.735(-3)? (STDERR)     at done (/home/vallo/.meteor/packages/meteortesting_mocha-core/.6.1.2.1dvruze.m99s++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:838:7)
W20190809-11:38:56.736(-3)? (STDERR)     at Runner.<anonymous> (/home/vallo/.meteor/packages/meteortesting_mocha-core/.6.1.2.1dvruze.m99s++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:918:5)
W20190809-11:38:56.736(-3)? (STDERR)     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
W20190809-11:38:56.736(-3)? (STDERR)     at Runner.emit (events.js:208:7)
W20190809-11:38:56.736(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/vallo/.meteor/packages/meteortesting_mocha-core/.6.1.2.1dvruze.m99s++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:903:12
W20190809-11:38:56.736(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/vallo/.meteor/packages/meteortesting_mocha-core/.6.1.2.1dvruze.m99s++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:772:9
W20190809-11:38:56.737(-3)? (STDERR)     at next (/home/vallo/.meteor/packages/meteortesting_mocha-core/.6.1.2.1dvruze.m99s++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:362:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Installed chromedriver version is 76 and path is correct.

```
vallo@ubuntu:~$ chromedriver -v 
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864})
vallo@ubuntu:~$ whereis chromedriver
chromedriver: /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: 'This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74'. You can try upgrading Chrome Driver version ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.25 -Supports Chrome version 76. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Already tried that, but the problem comes from Selenium not from ChromeDriver

Comment: Just curious do you have any reference for 'selenium-webdriver 3.6.0 which only supports Chrome version 74.' https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md

Comment: No, just have the error message. Edited with the full error log.

Comment: From message as far as I know you need to install https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/

Comment: yeah I installed that one, but get the same error. Locally chromedriver is 76 but looks like selenium is using another version.

Comment: Check System PATH for chrome driver https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/README.md

Comment: I guess it is correct. Edited with that info.

Comment: Just last question. On local what is the error message.

Comment: as running the tests locally? same error.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution would be to find a 74 version of Chrome.

An alternate, not great solution, would be to disable the client-side tests to at least avoid the issue on CI and let the server-side tests continue to run:

https://github.com/meteortesting/meteor-mocha#run-only-server-or-only-client-tests

Add `TEST_CLIENT=0` to your script command and the client-side tests will be skipped.